# how do i populate autocomplete search with database items

Tags: jquery, database, autocomplete

i will like to populate a Jquery autocomplete search with database items... rather than using an "names" with a list of names assigned to it, can i search from my database source ?

```
$(function() {
    var names = [ "sandy", "ruga", "malicka" ];

    var normalize = function( term ) {
        var ret = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
            ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $( "#developer" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
                value = value.label || value.value || value;
                return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
            }) );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example from jQuery UI auto-complete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

The basic idea goes like:

```
...
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON( "yourserver/data.php", {...params...}, response );
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is:

```
if(User starts typing in search box) {

    Fire keydown event in JavaScript {

        Send ajax request to your database,
            return a JSON object with relevant data

        Populate a list with those hits

        Assign said list to autocomplete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX.

AJAX is used to send requests to a remote server and then receive the data from the server.

At the server side, you can make a service that will take the specific requests and in response send the result. After that, you can save the result in the list and do what you are doing now.